# Get a concatenated list of items from multiple documents in flutter / firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firebase database which has a collection called "quizzes" where each quiz is a document with several questions in it.

Now, I am trying to create a list questions from multiple "quiz" documents, and pass them on to a pageview builder in flutter.

However, I am having trouble getting a list of items from multiple documents in flutter. The code works till the point where I can get a list of quizzes from various topics as I indicated below, but when I try to get the list of items using two functions below, I still get an empty list at the end.

I am new to flutter and asynchronous programming. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
class PracticeScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  List<Question> questions = [];

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      builder: (_) => QuizState2(),
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: Global.topicsRef.getData(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snap) {
          var state = Provider.of<QuizState2>(context);

          if (!snap.hasData || snap.hasError) {
            return LoadingScreen();
          } else {
            List<Topic> topics = snap.data;
            List<Quiz> quizzes =
                topics.map((topic) => topic.quizzes).expand((x) => x).toList();

            print(quizzes.length);
            print(quizzes.map((quiz) => quiz.description).toList());

// the code works till this point where I get a list of quizzes from multiple topics
            quizzes.map((quiz) => _getQuestions3(quiz.id));

// the questions array still remains empty at this point. 
            print(questions.map((question) => question.text).toList());

            return Scaffold(
              body: PageView.builder(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                controller: state.controller,
                onPageChanged: (int idx) =>
                    state.progress = (idx / (questions.length + 1)),
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int idx) {
                  //return Text('Sample');
                  return QuestionPage2(question: questions[idx]);
                },
                itemCount: questions.length - 1,
              ),
              bottomNavigationBar: AppBottomNav(),
            );

          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  _getQuestions2(String quizId) async {
    Future quizData = Document<Quiz>(path: 'quizzes/$quizId').getData();
    quizData.then((quizdata) {
      questions = questions..addAll(quizdata.questions.toList());
    });
  }

  _getQuestions3(String quizId) async {
    await _getQuestions2(quizId);
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what ended up working for me.

I think having multiple firestone queries within one async function was easier than trying to go through multiple functions.

```
 Future<List<Question>> getQuestions() async {
    var firestore = Firestore.instance;
    var topicsSnap = await firestore.collection('topics').getDocuments();
    var quizzes =
        (topicsSnap.documents.map((topic) => topic.data['quizzes'])).toList();
    var quizids = quizzes.map((quizitem) => quizitem[0]['id']).toList();
    var questions = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < quizids.length; i++) {
      var quizid = quizids[i];
      var quizsnap = await firestore.document('quizzes/$quizid').get();
      var quizQuestions = quizsnap.data['questions'];
      questions.addAll(quizQuestions);
    }
    var question2 = questions.map((v) => Question.fromMap(v)).toList();
    return (question2);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the following line is wrong:

`questions = questions..addAll(quizdata.questions.toList());`

Per [Dart/Flutter documentation](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.7.0/dart-core/List/addAll.html) addAll function is a so-called `void` function. This means it only does the job and does not return anything after that.

`questions..addAll()` adds quizdata to the questions list and returns nothing (`null`). By calling `questions = questions..addAll()` you essentially overwrite your questions list with `null`.

Replace

`questions = questions..addAll(quizdata.questions.toList());`

with the following line to fix this issue:

`questions.addAll(quizdata.questions.toList());`

The whole function should then look like:

```
_getQuestions2(String quizId) async {
  Future quizData = Document<Quiz>(path: 'quizzes/$quizId').getData();
  quizData.then((quizdata) {
    questions.addAll(quizdata.questions.toList());
  });
}
```